# How to click on the first link of an opensecrets page without getting an indexError?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on the first link in the results page of an [opensecrets.org](https://www.opensecrets.org) query. I've searched "chase" using selenium, and I now want to go to the page of the first link available. Eventually I want to loop through a whole list of searches and click on the first link, but now I can't even get my code to run with this one element's specific xpath. When I run this code:

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="___gcse_0"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a')[0]
result.click()
```

I get an error: IndexError: list index out of range. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error or is there a more general way to do this, so that I could do it with any search? I keep seeing answers to click on the first link of a google search, but they all use the tag_name "cite" so I'm unsure of how to apply this to an opensecrets search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to just click on the first link, you can use the below xpath  :

```
(//a[contains(@class, 'gs-title')])[1]
```

and in code, you can use it like this  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[contains(@class, 'gs-title')])[1]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC4
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

and if you'd like to do it from loop :

```
counter = 1
action = ActionChains(driver)
for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"(//a[contains(@class, 'gs-title')])[{counter}]"):
    action.move_to_element(link).click().perform()
    if counter == 1:
        break
    counter = counter + 2
```